# Setting channel volume in ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pcm

My app plays raw PCM audio data through various channels using ALSA. I'm allocating a new audio channel by using snd_pcm_open(), then setting the PCM format via the snd_pcm_hw_params_xxx() calls and finally feeding raw PCM audio data to ALSA by using the snd_pcm_writei() API.

This is all working fine so far but I haven't found any way to tell ALSA to reduce the volume of a sound channel allocated in the way outlined above. Of course, I could just manually apply volume scaling to the PCM data before sending it to ALSA via snd_pcm_writei() but is there really no way to have ALSA do this on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALSA has no such function.

You have to do the scaling yourself, or use a sound server like PulseAudio.

Answer (score 2):

**You can via amixer:**

```
amixer cset name='Headphone Playback Volume' 98%,100%
```

To get the name value - check alsamixer, appending 'Playback Volume' to each.

**And via alsamixer:**

Keyboard z is left channel decrease.

q is left increase.

and

c is right decrease.

e is right increase

Comment: I'm looking to do it programmatically not via external programs.

Comment: Amixer is not really an external program. It is a standard utility that comes with ALSA. You can call it from any other program. I work with Linux audio quite a lot and this is what I usually use. It is, by far, the easiest way of setting per-channel volume and I found it to be reliable.